# How to enable hover tab on page load in css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I am working on a [website](https://jsfiddle.net/wpy496v3/embedded/result) in which I want to **enable hover on page load**.

The HTML code which I have used for the tabs are:

```
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>
```

The CSS code which I have use in order to enable **London tab content** is:

```
.tab-contents>.active
{
display:block;
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wpy496v3/embedded/result)  so that **on page load London tab is always enable with hover**. The content section is already enabled, I just want to enable the tab now with hover.

Comment: Why don't you just add the active class to button before loading? `<button class="tablinks active" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>`

Comment: @git-e-up Can you make changes in the fiddle ? In that way, it would be easy for me to visualize.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wpy496v3/9/

Comment: @git-e-up It solves half my problem. On hovering `Paris and Tokyo tabs`, the london tab is still on hover.  I want to work in a way that `when page loads the london should have the background color which is present in the 
fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wpy496v3/9/embedded/result which is changed by you but on hovering `Paris` and `Tokyo` tabs the london tab hover should not be present.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your script:

```
var $activeTab = document.querySelector('.tablinks:first-child');
$activeTab.classList.toggle('active');
```

Comment: Can you make changes in the existing fiddle ? In that way, it would be easy for me to visualize.